# Select IP Addresses Used By More Than One User

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table containing, in part, user names and ip addresses, similar to below.

- IP Address      | User's Name
- 198.xxx.xxx.101 | User 1
- 198.xxx.xxx.102 | User 1
- 209.xxx.xxx.103 | User 2
- 124.xxx.xxx.104 | User 3
- 150.xxx.xxx.105 | User 4
- 150.xxx.xxx.105 | User 5

I'm trying to devise a query that will return ip addresses that have been used by more than one user, as well as the name of the user. So, given the above, the only records I would like returned would be the last two, because there are two different users using the same address.

I've tried

```
SELECT [IP Address], [User's Name]
FROM tempIPFails
GROUP BY [IP Address], [User's Name]
HAVING COUNT([User's Name]) > 1
ORDER BY [IP Address], [User's Name]
```

But this returns no records at all.

Can someone please help me get on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your query returns no rows is because you are grouping by the users name.  To get what you want:

```
SELECT [IP Address]
FROM tempIPFails
GROUP BY [IP Address]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY [IP Address];
```

If you want the full records associated with those IP addresses, then join this back to the original data:

```
select tipf.*
from tempIPFails tipf join
     (SELECT [IP Address]
      FROM tempIPFails
      GROUP BY [IP Address]
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) badips
     on tipf.[IP Address] = badips.[IP Address];
```

Comment: Hang on - one of us has got this backwards... it's me!

Answer (score 1):

i think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT [IP Address], COUNT([User's Name])
FROM tempIPFails
GROUP BY [IP Address]
HAVING  COUNT([User's Name]) > 1
ORDER BY [IP Address]
```

you need to group by ID_ADDRES and then count how many names match the same ip.
u was almost there :)

Comment: Thanks! This totally works, but I've marked Gordon's response as the answer because of the join back to original data.

Comment: its ok :) just make shure his answer work (for future visitors)